# Setting the rest of a horizontal navigation bar to another color?

Tags: css

Forgive me for not create a jsfiddle. I hope this will be reasonably simple for the experienced.

On [this site](https://www.wascc.com.au), I hope to make the area designated by the green region in the image below, have the same background as the black **Login** navigation button (`#menu-item-661`) which is `https://www.wascc.com.au/wp-content/themes/WASCC/images/sign-shap.jpg`. (on the site the green region is yellow)

[image]

I've tried:

```
#menu-item-661::after {
    content: "<img src="images/sign-shap.jpg" width="100%" />"
}
```

which didn't work, and:

```
#menu-item-661::after {
    content: "<li id="black-tab">&nbsp;</li>";
}
#black-tab {
    background-image: "images/sign-shap.jpg";
    width: auto;    
}
```

which didn't work, and:

```
nav {
    width: auto;
}
```

which didn't work.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

add the yellow background to your li elements like this:

```
ul#menu-not-logged-in li {
    font: 16px/51px oswaldregular;
    color: #48391f;
    background: url(/images/navi-shap.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/navigation-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

and add the black background to your whole nav like this:

```
nav {
height: 51px;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(images/sign-shap.jpg) repeat-x;
    font: 16px/51px oswaldregular;
    width: auto;
}
```

Then you have it just like in your screenshot
[image]

**EDIT** The arrows:

```
#menu-not-logged-in li .sub-menu li::before {
    content: "\203A";
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin: -11px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: That's great @noa-dev. Thank you. One other thing: can you see what is producing the white arrow to the left of each drop down navigation item? Unfortunately I can't.

Comment: I edited my answer. If it helps you you can accept it as answer.